# How to determine the period of composite functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

For exemple, take :$f\left(x\right)=$**cos**$\left(2x\right)\cdot \:$**sin**$\left(3x\right)$. Period of **cos**$\left(2x\right)$ is $\pi$ and that of **sin**$\left(3x\right)$ is $\frac{2\pi }{3}$. But why is the period of $f\left(x\right)$ $2\pi$?

For good measure, here's another example: How do I prove that the period of $f\left(x\right)=\frac{tan\left(x\right)}{1+sin\left(x\right)}$ is $2\pi$?

Comment: $f$ is the product of two functions, not the composition of two functions.

Comment: $2\pi$ is the LCM, the least common multiple, of the periods of the other functions.

Comment: @Mason. Ok, but why is it like that? I mean, why do we use the LCM? I was kind of searching to build a strong intuitive notion...

Answer (score 4):

$$ f(x)=\cos(2x)\sin(3x)=g(x)h(x)$$
Since $g$ is $\pi-$periodic and $h$ is $\frac{3\pi}{2}-$periodic and $\pi\neq\frac{3\pi}{2}$, then it is clear that the period $T$ of $f$ is a multiple of $\pi$ (to guaranty that the periodicity of $g$) and a multiple of $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ (to guaranty that the periodicity of $h$) at the same time.
Hence, $T$ is the $LCM(\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2})=2\pi$

You can use the same logic to answer the second question.

Comment: However this proves only that $2\pi$ is a period, not that it is the smallest period. For example, while $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ have smallest period $2\pi$, their product has smallest period $\pi$.In this case, looking at the zeros of $f(x)$ yields that a smaller period would have to be $\pi$, but we have $f(x+\pi)=-f(x)$.

Comment: Yes that's right. to find the smallest period one must solve the equation $f(x+T)=f(x)$ for $T$.